# Convert from sequential grid index to row, column index?

Tags: arrays, indexing, row, sequential, col

I have a 2D m x m array, and I want to go from sequential index ( the nth position ) to row, column index
I tried to come up with a method to calculate them, but I am not certain if they are right.

For example the sequential position 2, is row = 0, col = 1

```
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---|---|---|
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
|---|---|---|
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
|---|---|---|
```

Are the calculations to get the row, column index these?

```
row = (int)((n-1 / m))
col = ((n -1) % m )
```

How would these be modified to for a q x t array?

```
row = (int)((n-1 / q))
col = ((n -1) % t )
```